# MySQL service stop while doing a DUMP

Tags: mysql

We can't backup our Mysql DB. We have it under windows 2003.

It's mysql 5.1

So when we start dumping, the service stop after 3-4 sec.

The database work and the site it power work fine.

We need to move this DB to another server.

Thanks for any help

Comment: If the service stops, I guess the site goes down too?

Comment: If you can't get the dump working, and the server versions are very close, you could try just moving the mysql binary files and see if the new host can load them.

Comment: What mysql engine are you using? If it happens to be MyISAM you can simply move the data files one by one (3 files per table).

Comment: How are you attempting to dump your database? Have you checked the logs to see if there are any hints there?

Answer (score -1):

you can use another way of backup as a workaround solution. you can use raw backup if it is MyISAM. just copy the data folder from old server to the new server.

Comment: Hi, In fact if I go table by table, only 2 tables cause the service to stop. I can open them, but not dump them.